# How to change the start parameter to page 12 & above in Google custom search

Tags: search, google-api, google-search-api

To change the page of Google custome search page, I have to set the `start` parameter. Knowing that, the valid parameters value starts from 1, and add 10 to move to the next page (i.e, `start` parameter for page2=11). I need to know, if I want to set the start parameter to page 12, how can I write the number? Reference to googl:

```
Valid values are integers between 1 and (101 - num).
```

I can not understand what is `(101 - num)` ?? I tried many different guesses, nothing works. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

it means you can only request a maximum of 100 pages (when num = 1 or when you ask one result per page). Or a maximum number of 10 pages when num parameter = 10.